# Sum of matrices in C++ using operator overloading(C++)

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I have got this code for adding two matrices using the overloaded '+' operator. But my program has some error. But I am not being able to find any of those. I am supposed to get two matrices from the user and then show the sum of these two matrices by using the overloading feature of C++. I have no problems in getting the input from the user and displaying each of those matrices individually. But once the overloading function is called, the code fails. I don't know where actually.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class matrix
{
    int r=0,c=0,i=0,j=0,e[10][10];
public:
    matrix getMatrix()
    {
        cout<<"Enter the no. of rows of matrix:"<<endl;
        cin>>r;
        cout<<"Enter the no. of columns of matrix:"<<endl;
        cin>>c;
        cout<<"Enter the elements of the matrix:"<<endl;
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<c;j++)
            {
                cin>>e[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    matrix operator +(matrix m)
    {
        matrix sumMatrix;
        for(i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<c; j++)
            {
                sumMatrix.e[i][j]=this->e[i][j]+m.e[i][j];
            }
        }
        return sumMatrix;
    }
    void displayMatrix()
    {
        for(i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            cout<<endl;
            for (j=0; j<c; j++)
            {
                cout<<this->e[i][j]<<"    ";
            }
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    cout<<"NOTE: In order to add matrices, they must have same dimension."<<endl;
    matrix m1,m2,m3;
    cout<<"1st matrix:"<<endl;
    m1.getMatrix();
    m1.displayMatrix();cout<<endl;
    cout<<"2nt matrix:"<<endl;
    m2.getMatrix();
    m2.displayMatrix();cout<<endl;
    m3=m1+m2;
    cout<<"The sum of the two matrices is:"<<endl;
    m3.displayMatrix();
    return 0;
}
```

My output
[here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNQpP.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you did not set the values of `r` and `c` of the returned object in the `operator+` function.

```
matrix operator +(matrix m)
{
    matrix sumMatrix;
    sumMatrix.r = this->r;
    sumMatrix.c = this->c;

    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            sumMatrix.e[i][j]=this->e[i][j]+m.e[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sumMatrix;
}
```

Also compiler expects `getMatrix()` to return the matrix.
Change your

```
matrix getMatrix() {...}
```

to (rename it too)

```
void readFromConsole() {...}
```